# Expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: <Fragment />

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I export the following component, why do I get the errors `Expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: <Fragment />. Did you accidentally export a JSX literal instead of a component?` and `Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got: object`?

```
const MyComponent = (
    <>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
    </>
)
export default MyComponent
```

This question is not the same as the linked questions. It relates to a specific error someone might find and google.

Comment: You know that `MyComponent` is a `JSX.Element` and not an actual component, right? If you want to export a `JSX.Element` and get an error, make a question about that with more clear naming.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to change the component into a function:

```
const MyComponent = () => (
    <>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
    </>
)
export default MyComponent
```

If you are using typescript, the return type is `React.ReactElement`